# Is there a way to link two droplists together

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdown, .net-6.0

I am developing an app where an admin can create a board that will be linked to a client and a server that belong to this client. The `createBoard` page displays a `SelectListItem` with all the clients and another with all the servers.

The issue is that it is possible to select a server that do not belong to the currently selected client like this :

[image: example]

How can I make it so when a client is selected, only the servers related to this client show in the second dropdown list ?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT**

As requested I am adding the code I am using :

Here is the controller that allows me to inject data into the create view :

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Create()
{
    ViewBag.Clients = new SelectList(_clients, "ClientId", "CompanyName");
    ViewBag.Servers = new SelectList(_servers, "ServerId", "ServerName");
    return View();
}
```

_clients and _servers are two lists.

The view looks like that

[View code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1LyO.png)

PS: I used a screenshot, apparently the code sample options doesn't like the Razor syntax.

So as you can see this is very simple but this would allow user to select Alice as a Client and a server that belongs to Bob which is less than ideal and wanted.

Comment: 1) The simplest way is to use the [$.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) jquery. 2) Code related question without code in it is unlikely to get useful answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have added code samples from my project. Tell me if you need more